# Who or what is the subject of Andrea Bocelli's "Gloria the Gift of Life"?

Tags: song-lyrics, andrea-bocelli

"[Gloria the Gift of Life](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjCQOr35mQk)" is a song by Andrea Bocelli. It's beautiful, but I can't quite figure out what it's about.

- It seems like it could be God. "Gloria" is a [traditional Catholic exaltation](https://www.catholic.org/prayers/prayer.php?p=139) to God ("I raise my voice to sing") and the first few lyrics express gratitude for a variety of phenomena:

  > For the air we breathe
  >   For the tears we cry
  >   For every melody
  >   For the times we break
  >   Even when we bleed
  >   For the morning sun

  Some of the other lyrics seem very inapt in this context, though: "You were just a child/ only yesterday/ and now here you are/ here on your wedding day." That's not something a believer would say about God.
- It could be about a child (named Gloria, even). But why would you thank your child for "the air we breathe," and things like that?
- It could be a romantic love song, certainly, since that is Andrea Bocelli's best-known genre. But somehow that doesn't seem quite right for a song about a child grown up, and, similar to the previous point thanking one's partner for things like the "the air we breathe" or "the morning sun" seems a little off.

Who is the subject of the song? Is there a clue in the lyrics? Has Andrea Bocelli mentioned anything about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed about a wedding. I guess the first verse is just general thankfulness for the (wedding) day (with God implied) before the second verse is more specific.
Andrea Bocelli speaks about it in this video:

[Andrea Bocelli - Gloria the Gift of Life (Commentary)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WECD1l0r0EQ)

Comment: Can you summarize the video in your answer?